# Syntax Coloring for "Possible Unwanted Assignment" Issue

Tags: front-end, syntax, assignment, interface, syntax-highlighting

Apparently Mathematica's syntax coloring engine believes that the second assignment in the following code excerpt (concocted for illustration purposes only) is a "Possible Unwanted Assignment" since unchecking this box in Preferences causes the red highlighting to disappear:

[image]

Any ideas why Mathematica should believe that this assignment is possibly unwanted?  The variable `b` is used after all in the test conditional for the `While` loop whereas `f` and `g` are not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because you are using `=` (the assignment operator) in the *condition* (not the body) of `While`.  It is a typical beginner mistake to use `=` where `==` is meant, so Mathematica warns about this.

Since you also use several `;` in the condition, it gets a little confused and only highlights one of the `=` signs, not all of them.

Comment: Presumably then more experienced users will want to switch off highlighting for "Possible Unwanted Assignments" (which is enabled by default).